# Drupal: How to automatically send (cck) node content + file attachment via email

Tags: email, drupal, cck

I am still quite new to Drupal and have very limited programming skills.

I am trying to build a job board site using cck + views. I have created 2 related content types: a "job post" and a "job application" - both are related using a nodereference field.

The job application node has 4 fields: id of the job post to which the person is applying, email of the applicant, cover letter (body field) and attached cv (cck field that allows users to attach/upload a document).

Question: Once a job application is created I would like the content of the node (including the attached file) to be automatically sent via email to the person who posted the job (destination email address is in a cck field in the related "job post" node).

Thus my requirements are: (1) to automtically "transfer" the destination email address from the "job post" content type to the "job application" content type; and (2) to automatically send all the "job application" node contents + file attachment to the destination email.

Is there any module that can help me achieve this?

Thank you so much for your support.

My email address is: wedge.paul@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

To give it to you straight: No, there is no module that will do this. Largely because you have already made most content types and it is pretty unique to your project.

Still, you may not have limited programming skill, I would advice learning it when working with drupal. What you are asking is really not that hard to create by writing a custom module. Writing a custom module is really not that hard, and starting to write a custom module in Drupal is really well documented.

I can tell you what to use in the custom module, however it is better if you create it yourself (for future projects).

So you create your custom module:

```
function mymod_nodeapi{ //here all the action happens when a node is created
  switch ($op) {
    //if the node is inserted in the database
    case 'insert':
      //if node is a job application
      if($node->type = "jobapplication"){
          //using node_load function, you can load other nodes in a variable
          $relatednode = node_load($node->nodereference);

          //using drupal_mail function, you can mail people
          drupal_mail();
      }
      break;   
   }
}
```

This code has not been tested and can't be copy pasted. However node_load and drupal_mail as well as hook_nodeapi... use those functions and you'll get there.

Answer (score 0):

Lullabot's video tutorial "[Learning CCK for Drupal](http://store.lullabot.com/products/learning-cck)" is based on the concept of a job application/posting site as a case study. It may be worth investigating.

*no, I'm not connected in any way to Lullabot; just a fellow Drupaler*